# Exportar query para arquivo CSV com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Tenho um código em PHP que faz uma query no banco de dados e era para retornar os valores para um arquivo CSV, mas isso não está acontecendo. O script até está retornando a query, porém os valores ficam somente no navegador e o arquivo CSV não é criado. Estou usando serialize, seria este o problema?

```
<?php
    $DB = new ConexaoBD();
    $DB->ligarBD($NOME_BD, $USER_DB, $PASS_DB, $NOME_SERVIDOR);
    $row = $DB->executarSQL($query);
    $DB->fecharBD();

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($row);echo "</pre>";
    //ob_implicit_flush();

    header('Content-Encoding: ISO-8859-1');
    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Extracao_SkinAge.csv;');

    //header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    //header( 'Pragma: no-cache');

    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    //fputs($f, "teste arquivo");
    //fputs($f, "\n");

    $comma_separated = implode(";", $array_nomes);

    fputs($f, $comma_separated);
    fputs($f, "\n");

    foreach ($row as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, ";");
    }

    fclose($f);
    exit();

}
?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como exportar uma tabela para CSV usando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9596/como-exportar-uma-tabela-para-csv-usando-php)

Comment: Provavelmente tem algum espaço antes dos headers.